# Product URL in a shared shopping cart in Magento multi-store websites

Tags: php, magento, shopping-cart, magento-1.9

I have Magento multi-store websites that I want that the user will be able to add products to his shopping cart from all the website and pay once.

I successfully done it using [this article](http://turnkeye.com/blog/share-magento-cart-between-multistores).

But when the user click on the product in the shopping cart, he is not redirected to the right website. It's a limitation the described in the article at the end.

> The link for editing items in the cart will redirect customer to
>   original cart website. It is possible to change it, you can override
>   getUrl method for cart items block or override controller.

I couldn't find any explaination to how to do this override.

Someone can help me do this?

Thanks

Comment: Hii Nir, I'm having a same issue. Did you find any solution. if Yes please help me. I'm really in trouble.

Comment: No... still search for a solution...

Answer (score 1):

In my case i seen file of cart's item.phtml, it was using getproducturl(). 
So, I modified that method in file /app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Item/Renderer.php line 152. 
I made condition that if its main website don't change otherwise it adds stores code in url like www.example/store1/Producturl.

I hope This will Help You.

As You Require The File method. Check belowed code.

```
    public function getProductUrl()
        {
            if (!is_null($this->_productUrl)) {
                return $this->_productUrl;
            }
            if ($this->getItem()->getRedirectUrl()) {
                return $this->getItem()->getRedirectUrl();
            }

            $product = $this->getProduct();
            $option  = $this->getItem()->getOptionByCode('product_type');
            if ($option) {
                $product = $option->getProduct();
            }
            $webids = $product->getWebsiteIds();
            $wid = array();
            foreach($webids as $webid){
                $wid[] = $webid;
            }
            if(!in_array(1,$wid)){
                $website = Mage::app()->getWebsite($wid[0])->getCode();
                $org_url = $product->getUrlModel()->getUrl($product);
                $mod_url = str_replace("www.example.com/index.php/","www.example.com/".$website."/index.php/",$org_url);
                return $mod_url;
            }
            return $product->getUrlModel()->getUrl($product);
        }
```

As my first website id was "1", that's why i used in_array(1.$wid). You Can use your main website id over there. and in str_replace u can use baseurl() method of main website instead of static value i used.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. can you please publish your modified files?

Comment: Hii, Please Make a comment this helped U or not.

Comment: There is no need to use string replace.

Once you have determined the store_id you want to generate the URL for, just pass that as a param to the getUrl() call.

    return $product->getUrlModel()->getUrl($product, array('_store' => $realStoreId));